# how to use ractive as view component in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, ractivejs

I am new to ractive.js and want to integrate it with backbone.js. I found a backbone adapter for ractive howevere didn't found a sample which will show to use it effectively. 
Need a sample that explain how to use ractive.js as a view component in backbone.js

Answer (score 3):

Since the official demo seems to be down, I was able to put together a simple  demo based on the rest of documentation.

Basically include ractive and [ractive adapter for backbone](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive-adaptors-backbone) after backbone and dependencies, then in your view's render method initialize a new ractive view passing it the backbone view's element, template and model data as `el`, `template` and `data` respectively as shown in below example.

For one way bindings, use the model getter method like `{{model.get('prop')}}`
and for two way bindings directly refer the property like {{`model.attributes.name`}}

Also, to avoid possibility of memory leak, override backbone view's `remove` method and have it destroy it's ractive view before removing itself.

Hope the comment explains the process:

```js
// Nothing special, create a model instance with data
var model = new Backbone.Model({
  name: "John"
});

// Backbone view constructor
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: $('#ractiveTest').html(),
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },
  events: {
    'click button': 'remove'
  },
  render: function() {
    //initialize ractive view as part of rendering
    this.ractive = new Ractive({
      el: this.el, // pass the view's element to ractive
      template: this.template, // pass the view's template to ractive
      data: {
        user: this.model // pass view's model data to ractive
      }
    });
  },
  //override view's remove method to destroy ractive instance as well
  remove: function() {
    // Just for added safety
    this.ractive.teardown();
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
  }
});

// initialize the view and pass in the model.
var view = new View({
  model: model
});

// append the view to DOM
view.$el.appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.1/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ractive/0.7.3/ractive.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/ractive.adaptors-backbone/latest/ractive-adaptors-backbone.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/template" id="ractiveTest">
  <label>
    Enter your name:
    <input value="{{user.attributes.name}}">
  </label>
  <p>Hello, {{user.get('name')}}!</p>
  <button>remove</button>
</script>
```

I find it a bit strange that we have to do `user.get('name')` in the template for one way binding and `user.attributes.name` for two way binding.

It could've been abstracted away in the Backbone adapter like`user.name` likes [rivets](http://rivetsjs.com/docs/guide/#adapters-creating) does.