# RactiveJS with Backbone Adaptor

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ractivejs

How would be the primary setup for RactiveJS with Backbonejs.
How ractive component can use backbone Model inside it and fetch data.
Not as [how to use ractive as view component in backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639707/how-to-use-ractive-as-view-component-in-backbone-js)

i want backbone to be injected in ractive component as adaptor.

Thanks

Comment: *"i want backbone to be injected in ractive component as adaptor."* - Backbone is a framework, so this sentence doesn't make any sense. If you don't want to create backbone view, you can directly create ractive view with the adaptor mentioned in question you linked to

Answer (score 0):

Ractive has a [Backbone adaptor](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive-adaptors-backbone). All you do is create your models and simply set them into Ractive as if they were regular JS objects and use Ractive as is.

The plugin *might* be a little dated, and I'm no Backbone expert myself. However, Ractive does have [extensive documentation on Adaptors](https://ractive.js.org/plugins/#adaptors). Should you wish to update the adaptor in case it doesn't work for you (or if it doesn't work on the latest Backbone version), feel free to fork and modify to suit your needs.